# How can i change width of navbar with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying a responsive design and I have a problem - the width of my #menu in css is 0, i choose the value of width by js, when input is checked

And now I must change the value of it's width for every screen size, how can I do it by changing css?
I tried it:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
#menu {
   height: 30px;
   width: 200px;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, because value set from js

How can I rewrite js for this?

```js
function togNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
  var basket = document.getElementById("basket1");
    if (nav.style.width == '420px') {
    nav.style.width = '0';
    nav.style.opacity = 1;
    basket.style.opacity = 1;
  } else {
    nav.style.width = "420px";
    nav.style.opacity = 1;
    basket.style.opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 49px;
    top: 10px;
    background: rgba(14, 13, 13, 0.7);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(14, 13, 13, 0.7);
}
#menu { 
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="togNav()">
    <span id="span1"></span>
    <span id="span2"></span>
    <span id="span3"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <nav class="nav-menu" id="menu">
       <ul>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('figurative1')">FIGURATIVE</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('painting1')">PAINTING</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('portret1')">PORTRET</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('stilllife1')">STILL LIFE</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onclick="openSection('landscape1')">LANDSCAPE</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/tatarusetskaya/pen/XWpzNZa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a responsive navbar or any other element. You should not fixed the width of element. You can use `max-width`. It will automatically decrease the width size of your navbar when your mobile size reaches to the assigned number of width.
And you can also change the width of any element using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can try in css with !important;

sample:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
#menu {
   height: 30px;
   width: 200px !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your width is always set to 0 is because your js code is applying that style inline, meaning it will generally override everything. To create a responsive nav you generally don't want to supply fixed width's to containers, preferably letting the containers content dictate the width. Using media queries is probably the right way to go. Also